# Unable to move Cloud Service (Extended Support) to another resource group

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

we have problem to move Cloud Service (Extended Support) from 1 resource group to another resource group in the same subscription. Both resource groups are in the same location.

[Picture with status of the move validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZX7p.png)

> Error code in validation window is:
> *{   "code": "ResourceMoveNotSupported",   "target": "/subscriptions/123456-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-123456/resourceGroups/AAAAA-BBBBB-Migrated/providers/Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices/AAAAA-BBBBB",
> "message": "Resource move is not supported for resource types
> 'Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices'." }*

Additional information:
Source resource group was created automatically after successful in-place migration from Cloud Service (Classic) to Cloud Service (Extended Support). Now we need to move all resources created by migration back to the original resource group, where Cloud Service (Classic) was previously located. Cloud Service (Classic) was automatically deleted after migration.

The main reason why we migrated from Cloud Service (Classic) to Cloud Service (Extended Support) was ability to move between subscriptions, but we are unable to move it even inside the same subscription :(

Any ideas how to proceed with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Best course of action is to create an Azure Support Ticket.

These type of operations are deep internal to azure, and reasons why these fail range from config errors, failed internal transactions to straight up bugs for a scenario they did not consider.

**Note**: it might take some time and patience on your side to get the desired results reached from Azure support, as these type of tickets are usually low priority.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've put the same question on MS docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/759482/unable-to-move-cloud-service-extended-support-to-a.html

Answer (score 0):

We finally managed to contact Azure Support.
This move is not supported :(

> Since the Cloud Service extended support is a new published product,
> we are sorry that currently it does not support migration from one
> subscription to another. We are sorry that moving “Cloud Service
> extended support” among resource groups in the same subscription is
> also unsupported.